# How to get array of descendants from adjacency lists?

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table and data

```
CREATE TABLE relationships (a TEXT, b TEXT);
CREATE TABLE nodes(n TEXT);
INSERT INTO relationships(a, b) VALUES 
 ('1', '2'), 
 ('1', '3'),
 ('1', '4'),
 ('1', '5'),
 ('2', '6'),
 ('2', '7'),
 ('2', '8'),
 ('3', '9');
INSERT INTO nodes(n) VALUES ('1'), ('2'), ('3'), ('4'), ('5'), ('6'), ('7'), ('8'), ('9'), ('10');
```

I want to output

```
  n  |  children
  1  |  ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
  2  |  ['6', '7', '8', '9']
  3  |  ['9']
  4  |  []
  5  |  []
  6  |  []
  7  |  []
  8  |  []
  9  |  []
  10 |  []
```

I am trying to use `WITH RECURSIVE` but is stuck on how to pass parameter into CTE

```
WITH RECURSIVE traverse(n) AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM relationships
    WHERE a = n --- not sure how to pass data to here
    UNION ALL
    ...
)
WITH basic_cte AS (
    SELECT a1.n as n,
           (SELECT COALESCE(json_agg(temp), '[]')
            FROM (
                         (SELECT * FROM traverse(a1.a))
                 ) as temp
           ) as children
    FROM nodes as a1
)
SELECT *
FROM basic_cte;
```

Comment: @HansMusgrave yes that is correct

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name typo I'll fix thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a list of the children of all nodes, you need a left join to the nodes table

```
with recursive rels as (
  select a,b, a as root
  from relationships
  union all
  select c.*, r.root
  from relationships c
    join rels r on r.b = c.a
)
select n.n, array_agg(r.b) filter (where r.b is not null)
from nodes n
  left join rels r on r.root = n.n
group by n.n
order by n.n;
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: This ignores any empty children. You can add a left join like in [@a_horse_with_no_name's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62549914/3798897) to get that functionality.

You can't really pass a parameter into the CTE unless you veer off into stored procedures and whatnot. The CTE is a single table that needs to contain all the rows you might want to use from it.

Assuming a fairly nice graph (no duplicate edges, no cycles), code like the following ought to do what you're looking for.

- The base case for the recursive query gets all level-1 descendants (the children) for all nodes which could possibly be parents.
- The recursive step walks through the 2nd level, 3rd level, etc down the tree.
- Once we have all parent-descendant tuples we can aggregate the data as desired.

```
WITH RECURSIVE descendants(parent, child) AS (
    SELECT * FROM relationships
    UNION
    SELECT d.parent, r.b
    FROM descendants d JOIN relationships r ON d.child=r.a
)
SELECT parent AS n, array_agg(child) AS children
FROM descendants
GROUP BY parent
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This code provides alot of insight but it doesn't populate the empty children (I can achieve that with left join)

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing that out! I should have paid more attention to the desired output ;) Since it seems to have had some value for you I'll leave it as-is and just reference the other answer.

Comment: Hi  I just ran EXPLAIN ANALYZE on the CTE. Any idea why the estimated row count so high? `(cost=21776.23..29537.83 rows=388080 width=64) (actual time=0.053..0.148 rows=12 loops=1)` The actual row count is 12 but the estimated row is ~380k? I cannot find where this comes from

Comment: Accurately estimating recursive row counts without just running the query is an impossible problem in general (even for really simple queries), so postgres errs on the side of not trying at all. You might get away with something like https://pghintplan.osdn.jp/pg_hint_plan.html to help the query planner out if you have more information about the query you're running.

Comment: I solved it, just had to do abit of cleanup on old stats `VACUUM (ANALYZE) nodes;`
`VACUUM (ANALYZE) relationships;` Plan looks good now :) Thanks!